# Laravel Relationship Issues - one to one

Tags: php, orm, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I'm attempting to build my first application in Laravel and seem to have run into a problem with relationships.

I have Users and Staff_Members. A staff member is linked to a user account, see database schema below:

**staff_members:**

```
Schema::create('staff_members', function($table){
        $table->increments('staff_member_id');
        $table->unsignedInteger('user_id');
        $table->foreign('user_id')->references('user_id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade')->onUpdate('cascade');
        $table->string('first_name');
        $table->string('surname');
        $table->string('image');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

**users:**

```
Schema::create('users', function($table){
        $table->increments('user_id');
        $table->string('username');
        $table->string('password');
        $table->unsignedInteger('type_id')->nullable();
        $table->foreign('type_id')->references('type_id')->on('user_types')->onDelete('set null')->onUpdate('cascade');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

Here are my models:

**User:**

```
class User extends Eloquent  {

/**
 * The database table used by the model.
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $primaryKey = 'user_id';
protected $table = 'users';


public function staff_member(){
    return $this->hasOne('StaffMember', 'user_id');
}



}
```

**StaffMember:**

```
class StaffMember extends Eloquent {
protected $primaryKey = 'staff_member_id';
protected $table = "staff_members";

public function user(){

    return $this->belongsTo('User', 'user_id');
}

}
```

And here is what im running in my code:

```
$staff = StaffMember::find(1);
$user = User::find(1);
var_dump($staff->user); // Outputs the user correctly
var_dump($user->staff_member); // Outputs NULL
```

As you can see, the Staff to user relationship works fine and returns the user data, but the user to staff relationship always returns null. I really cant see what Im doing wrong here and am pulling my hair out, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Update:

Thanks to @Gregory I have discovered that the final $user->staff_member is not actually querying the database, although I am still cant figure out why this would be or how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have enough reputation to comment, so i'll do it this way.
Your code looks fine to me, have you tried printing out the sql that Laravel uses?

```
$queries = DB::getQueryLog();
$last_query = end($queries);
```

This will get your last executed query, print it out and you'll probably see the problem more easily.

Comment: I have added that Gregory after the but I only get "select * from `users` where `users`.`user_id` = 1 limit 1". Its as though the query for the link is never actually executed

Comment: Okay I can confirm the $user->staff_member isnt actually querying the database, up to that point there are 3 queries and after I call $user->staff_member there are still only 3 queries. Does this give you any ideas as to what it might be?

Comment: Did you do 'composer dump-autoload' in your terminal just to be shure, I'm going to try and recreate your problem

Comment: Okey, found it. Change the function to public function staffmember(){.. The underscore is the problem apparently. This worked for me, let me know if it works for you to!

Comment: That is fantastic thanks Gregory! I suppose I was going against the grain as now I look at laravel methods they are all usually camel case, im just surprised that an underscore isn't handled in any way and doesn't provide any feedback - I have spent hours looking at that, which annoys me as I chose to use a framework for the first time to speed up development. I will mark your answer as the solution - thanks a lot for your help!